# Basic concept missing

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

It is clear that I am not understanding something quite basic about jquery, to the extent that I am not even sure what to call it. I would hazard 'wrapped-set' and will use that term for now.

My scenario: using jquery Isotope for a language dictionary with letter buttons A-Z at top.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="element"> (say, 100 of these)
        <div class=titlePE></div>
        a few other divs
    </div>
</div>
```

It seems to me that the wrapped-set is cumulative in that it adds each new tile-set to the whole. This became clear when I tried numbering my tiles:

```
$(".letter").click(function() {
    $('.element').each(function(index) { // NUMBERS INCREMENTAL
         $(this).find('.titlePE').before('<p class="number">' + index + '</p>');
    }); 
});
```

The first letter-set A: 1, 2, 3... and the second B: 100, 101... etc. Return to A: 1,2,3... B: 100... I tried $('.element').detach(); (empty, remove) and numbering was, as expected: 0, 1, 2...

Questions:

1) I assume from the 0,1,2... that the wrapped-set is an array? I understand inherent iteration but that works on the whole. Is it possible to isolate a specific letter-set, an array sub-set; say 'C' as, for example: letter[2] or .element[0][2] - or some such?

2) If the wrapped-set is cumulative then how can I test if a particular letter-set has been loaded and avoid the ajax load every letter-click? This then leads me to think, 'why not just load all data at the get-go?' - assuming I can grab a letter-set on click, as 1) above? I am guessing there will be a total of about 800kb of data for this first-level, A-Z presentation. Not so huge. Two questions? 2a 2b

I googled, trawled the two books that I have and generally scratched various bodily parts but everything seems to relate to inherent iteration, a single block of data. I am sorry if all this wanders unduly but hope you can give me some direction or tease out my thoughts further or give me some key words or jquery functions that I can research. I need something. A new hobby :) I am keen to learn so *any* guidance would be appreciated. Many thanks if you have read this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will return a result set based on the selector you provide.  The returned jQuery object is backed by an array of DOM elements matching the provided selector.

You can (and should when using Isotope) assign additional classes to your elements to aid in selection.  It doesn't *have* to be classes - Isotope will work with any jQuery selectors, but class based selectors will be more efficient. That is the general approach used in the [Isotope Documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html) as well.

For example, when adding elements in the `a` set, assign the class `a` to it.

The resulting HTML would look something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="element a">…</div>
    <div class="element a">…</div>
    <div class="element b">…</div>
    <div class="element b">…</div>
    …
</div>
```

The test if a set has been loaded then becomes as simple as:

```
if($('.a').length)  // if truthy (non-zero) this set is loaded
```

Comment: Yes, I just read a bit on filter and have set class=a etc. More fluke than plan :) **repeat comment** below (in case u missed) So, there is no clear block separation? Can this be set onload?

Comment: When using Isotope, I'd use the class based selectors - they can be set onload.  With that approach, you can get different lists based on the selectors you provide jQuery and/or Isotope: i.e.: all a elements ==> $('.element.a'), all a & b elements ==> $(.element.a, .element.b).  While I haven't explicitly tried using Isotope with child elements in different containers it *may* be possible, but I'm guessing you'd spend more time trying to figure out how to get Isotope working in that model.

Comment: replying quicker than I can type :) I have a bit of a handle on this and some homework to do. No direction is like... lost? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the result of this DOM query is a jQuery-wrapped array of matching elements and the order of the array's elements is based on position of each element in the DOM. If you want to filter the returned array, you can use jQuery's [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method. For checking whether a specific element exists or not, you can use [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property.

For autopsying the returned collection you can use `console.log()`/`console.dir()`.

Comment: So, there is no clear block separation? Can this be set onload? ... filter first then length > 1 = set exists? I will read more on filter options. Q. 2b - the efficiency of loading 800k of data v's individual loads?

Comment: @Arfa If by block, you mean children if a wrapper element, yes, you can select children of a block, just like using CSS selectors and it can be done on page load. Well, I would load them individually, to me 800kb is a big size for an ajax request.

Comment: OK, a bit of fog is clearing. I still need to work with this more and read but it seems data is loaded as a single block and massaged as required - filter, selectors... Each letter click will add to the wrapped whole (is that what its called?). 800k - yes, best test then load. I'll check dc5's answer if that's OK? You have **way** mucho brownie points. Awesome. I see I am now up to 15! (and counting). A big thumbs up all round.